# In wso2 identity server custom grant giving Referential integrity constraint violation

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using wso2 identity server 5.8.0 so, I tried to use the custom grant type example jar given in wso2 identity server doc https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Writing+a+Custom+OAuth+2.0+Grant+Type (**mobile grant type**). It is working and giving accesstoken also but when I include oidc scope openid it is giving me error.

request:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://x.x.x.x:9443/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic dm13dHRpjhkjjkhjkjMnF6b0szY1k3Z3ZneVlh' \
--header 'Cookie: requestedURI=../../api/server/v1/oidc/scopes/openid; JSESSIONID=6DDF48CEB24DCBFA0EA8275944D96120' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=mobile' \
--data-urlencode 'mobileNumber=0333444' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=openid'
```

Exception which is thrown after adding scope is:

```
[2020-07-24 07:50:06,971] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service} -  Error occurred while issuing the access token for Client ID : vmwttiaSrx__GN1O5Yql5Tuegy8a, User ID null, Scope : [openid] and Grant Type : mobile
org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.IdentityOAuth2Exception: Error occurred while storing new access token : a59deb0f-d008-3afe-9ca6-a141dfc60e78
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler.storeAccessToken(AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler.java:351)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler.persistAccessTokenInDB(AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler.java:452)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler.generateNewAccessTokenResponse(AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler.java:383)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler.issue(AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler.java:168)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.AccessTokenIssuer.issue(AccessTokenIssuer.java:276)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service.issueAccessToken(OAuth2Service.java:247)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.token.OAuth2TokenEndpoint.issueAccessToken(OAuth2TokenEndpoint.java:305)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.token.OAuth2TokenEndpoint.issueAccessToken(OAuth2TokenEndpoint.java:91)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:193)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:103)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:216)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:220)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.filter.AuthorizationHeaderFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationHeaderFilter.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:65)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1137)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1780)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.IdentityOAuth2Exception: Error when storing the access token for consumer key : vmwttiaSrx__GN1O5Yql5Tuegy8a
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.AccessTokenDAOImpl.insertAccessToken(AccessTokenDAOImpl.java:261)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.AccessTokenDAOImpl.insertAccessToken(AccessTokenDAOImpl.java:98)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.AccessTokenDAOImpl.insertAccessToken(AccessTokenDAOImpl.java:301)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler.storeAccessToken(AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler.java:348)
        ... 68 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "CONSTRAINT_B1A: PUBLIC.IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE FOREIGN KEY(TOKEN_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN(TOKEN_ID) ('2180c2f1-5fd0-4954-9aad-a00baf36265a')"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE (TOKEN_ID, TOKEN_SCOPE, TENANT_ID) VALUES (?,?,?) [23506-175]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:332)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:172)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:149)
        at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRowOwnTable(ConstraintReferential.java:368)
        at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRow(ConstraintReferential.java:310)
        at org.h2.table.Table.fireConstraints(Table.java:894)
        at org.h2.table.Table.fireAfterRow(Table.java:911)
        at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:162)
        at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:115)
        at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:79)
        at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:253)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.execute(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:193)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.AccessTokenDAOImpl.insertAccessToken(AccessTokenDAOImpl.java:221)
        ... 71 more
```

Answer (score 0):

By default AccessTokenIssuer try to add a value of **idp_id** inside IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN table and its a not_null field. In the error scenario, the value of `OAuth2Util.getAuthenticatedIDP(tokReqMsgCtx.getAuthorizedUser());` is **null** and `OAuth2ServiceComponentHolder.isIDPIdColumnEnabled()` is **true**, that's why a valid token is not created in the table. Hence, the exception has been occured at the time of value insertion into  IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE. So, we need to disable the IDPIDColumn using Oauth2 Service Component handler at the time validating grant.  `OAuth2ServiceComponentHolder.setIDPIdColumnEnabled(false);`